# Controlling check-out check-in

Tags: tfs

How do you set up either the check-out or check-in rules so that all users can add/remove files in the solution, but keep a single check-out on code files?

Comment: Arnej:  I'm not sure what you're asking here.  Please elaborate.  Also, don't repeat tags in your question title.  I've removed it for you.

Comment: I wanted to control who checked out certain files. In the end we just made rules that only certain areas were modified by certain people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the security model of version control.

You can right click on a folder in source control and then choose the Properties of the folder. Then go to the security tab to add granular security to version control.

Answer (score 0):

There is not clear way to do per file check-in /check-out rules by user.